# php mysql data only shows one row with foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

ok i have this and it doesn't show all the rows when fetched from mysql database its like this:

```
  mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
    $query_cat = "SELECT * FROM cat";
    $cat = mysql_query($query_cat, $config) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat);

    $arr = array("TIT" => $row_cat['title'],
            "DES" => $row_cat['description']);


    foreach($arr as $ar){
    echo $ar;
    }
```

now it only displays the first row and then stops why is it not displaying all the fields and i don't wanna use while loop for it can anyone explain me the problem??

EDIT: Well basically i want to work it like this

```
$p = "{TIT}{DES}";
foreach($arr as $k => $p){
$p = str_replace("{".$k."}", $v, $p);
echo $p;
}
```

Now the problem is not with str_replace its with the loop or database because the database rows are not incrementing and displays only one data.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` only fetches one row (http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

Comment: i have re edited the question please take a look...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will always return the first row. you are fetching  only once that will return only first row.

Instead you must fetch all the rows using fetch statement in loop

```
 while($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
       echo $row_cat['title'];
       echo $row_cat['description'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP `mysq_fetch_array` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> *"Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead"*

As far as I know, you cannot retrieve every row without using a loop. You should do something similar to this:

```
while($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
  echo $row_cat['title'];
  echo $row_cat['description'];
}
```